# iOS Crash when return from Background(home)

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

my app crash sometimes when user return from home
I can't find the reason from report crash :

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a1f90c8c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a1eb24e0 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 676
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b0d32b6c WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait+ 314220 (WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 144
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001b0d18a18 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void + 207384 ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2040
4   WebKit                          0x00000001a96593c4 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<std::__1::unique_lock<WTF::Lock> >+ 213956 (std::__1::unique_lock<WTF::Lock>&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 164
5   WebKit                          0x00000001a96591f8 IPC::Connection::waitForMessage+ 213496 (IPC::StringReference, IPC::StringReference, unsigned long long, WTF::Seconds, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::WaitForOption>) + 692
6   WebKit                          0x00000001a98d3f74 bool IPC::Connection::waitForAndDispatchImmediately<Messages::RemoteLayerTreeDrawingAreaProxy::CommitLayerTree>+ 2813812 (unsigned long long, WTF::Seconds, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::WaitForOption>) + 60
7   WebKit                          0x00000001a98d0294 WebKit::RemoteLayerTreeDrawingAreaProxy::waitForDidUpdateActivityState+ 2798228 (unsigned long long) + 116
8   WebKit                          0x00000001a987a284 WebKit::WebPageProxy::dispatchActivityStateChange+ 2445956 () + 732
9   WebKit                          0x00000001a97c42ec WebKit::ApplicationStateTracker::applicationWillEnterForeground+ 1700588 () + 44
10  Foundation                      0x00000001a2477e74 -[__NSObserver _doit:] + 316
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a20f409c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a20f40e4 ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 64
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a20f3444 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 368
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a20f30fc ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 104
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a206f43c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1416
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a20f2a4c _CFXNotificationPost + 1244
17  Foundation                      0x00000001a244f2d8 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 60
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a597e320 -[_UISceneLifecycleMonitor willEnterForeground] + 344
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a597f30c __111-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneLifecycleMonitor transitionToTargetState:fromState:withTransitionContext:preparations:]_block_invoke_2 + 168
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5e113ec _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 100
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a597f0c8 __111-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneLifecycleMonitor transitionToTargetState:fromState:withTransitionContext:preparations:]_block_invoke.114 + 144
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5984640 ___UISceneLifecycleSettingsUpdateBlockWithCanvasAndTransitionContext_block_invoke_2 + 356
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a597eba0 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneLifecycleMonitor transitionToTargetState:fromState:withTransitionContext:preparations:] + 804
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5984380 ___UISceneLifecycleSettingsUpdateBlockWithCanvasAndTransitionContext_block_invoke + 340
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5984ec8 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2 + 136
26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5d44028 +[BSAnimationSettings+ 5824552 (UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 824
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5e2a5ac _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 244
28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5984c34 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 136
29  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5e2a4a8 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
30  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5984aa0 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 376
31  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a57f9efc __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 636
32  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a57f8a64 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 248
33  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a57f9c34 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 220
34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a5d64e7c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 464
35  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a723243c -[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 544
36  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a7256e50 __88-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:updateWithSettingsDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 120
37  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a723c0f8 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 232
38  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a7256d84 __88-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:updateWithSettingsDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 184
39  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a1e66184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
40  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a1e4044c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 216
41  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a727b540 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
42  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a727b20c -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 404
43  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a727b734 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
44  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a21167e0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
45  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2116738 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 80
46  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a2115ed0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
47  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a211101c __CFRunLoopRun + 1080
48  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a21108bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
49  GraphicsServices                0x00000001abf7c328 GSEventRunModal + 104
50  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a61a66d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
51  wenxuecity                      0x00000001040b715c main + 29020 (main.m:16)
52  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a1f9b460 start + 4
```

I do nothing in the method applicationWillEnterForeground

I Just add [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp] in the method applicationDidBecomeActive

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application { 

    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

Comment: welcome to the stackoverflow. please share you appdelegate's `applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)`

Comment: Hey Yangfan Deng, welcome to stackoverflow, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking your first question. :)

Comment: seems like you are using webkit, if yes then goto project>Build Phases>Link Binary with Libraries> add WebKit.framework and then check if problem still persists.